# Panning around center view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

This is a bit of a continuation of my last question, but I'm at a loss as to how I should approach this. I have a center view that is dynamic and changed via three options panels. An example of this is shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOkPp.gif

I realize that I should be using the Pan Gesture to move it around, but I'm new to xCode and a bit lost with how to add the momentum and snap to the views. I considered using paging in a scrollview to achieve the effect, but I'm not sure I'll be able to do that.

I would really appreciate a bit of a kickstart in the direction I should be going.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for open source control which other developers has developed if you are new to xcode. 
Try this one:
https://github.com/MarcoSero/MSMatrixController

This is something similar to what you want. You will need little modification here to achieve your desired look.

Thanks!